# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:[]('id' ))

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

1. When implemented my own firebase with the app, I get this error and no products showing when I click on a Restaurant?

so the error is:

> NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on
> null. Receiver: null Tried calling: )

In File Restaurant.dart. in Providers Folder.

And occurs on:

```
loadSingleRestaurant({String restaurantId}) async{

    final restaurant = await _restaurantServices.getRestaurantById(id: restaurantId);

    notifyListeners();

  }
```

2. -- And no 2 error occurs this:

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0dEZ.png)

These are shown in Debug mode in flutter running on Galaxy s8 Device.
How to fix this.  help very appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it, It was occuring because of no Null check code, I had to create a If and else to make sure it allows non null values